# How to use gnome 43

Tags: linux, debian, gnome

I came from windows, and I have a small experience with ubuntu.

both these Operating systems provide a taskbar out of the box to see and switch between your running apps fast, sometimes when the person is carrying out some intensive work, he will be switching fast between many running apps ... and it would be natural to look at what is running and what not at all times on your main screen.

I installed debian 12, it has gnome 43 and there is no task bar, I don't see how people are supposed to use gnome. each time I want to swich between running apps I go to the activity screen to see what I have running and click on what I need ? Is this the way gnome is supposed to be used ? that's too slow and counter intuitive.

(I know shortcuts exist but so are taskbars in 10 operating systems that I tried)

Am I missing something ? I really do not understand how the out of box experience is supposed to be on gnome ? going back and forth to the activity screen ?

I like how gnome looks and I want to understand how to use it.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly how you're supposed to use it. And you already know keyboard shortcuts exist. If you don't like either, then either use extensions that suit you or find another DE. This is how GNOME has been since the first 3.x release years ago

Comment: There is not any strict correlation between the operating systems and the window manager being used.  Most desktop OS's allow you to choose one or more desktop environments so you really need to list the 10 OS's that you've tried and each of the desktop environments built in to each OS that you also tried. For example, the current Ubuntu environment supports 19 different desktops while REL look-alikes have 11 desktops available. Which combinations have you tried?